# How to concatenate values from many columns into one column when one doesn't know the number of columns will have

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

My application saves an indeterminate number of values in different columns. As a results, I have a data frame with a certain number of columns at the beginning but then from a particular column (that I know) I will have an uncertain number of columns saving same data

Example:

```
known1  known2 know3 unknow1 unknow2 unknow3 ...
1       3      3     data    data2   data3
```

The result I would like to get should be something like this

```
known1  known2 know3 all_unknow 
1       3      3     data,data2,data3
```

How can I do this when I don't know the number of unknown columns but what I do know is this will occur  (in this example) from the 4th column.

Comment: Your columns are really named known1, known2, known3, unknow1, etc... What is the name of the particular column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the columns by keyword:

```
cols = list(df.filter(like='unknow'))
# ['unknow1', 'unknow2', 'unknow3']

df['all_unknow'] = df[cols].apply(','.join, axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns=cols)
```

or take all columns from the 4th one:

```
cols = df.columns[3:]

df['all_unknow'] = df[cols].apply(','.join, axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns=cols)
```

output:

```
   known1  known2  know3        all_unknow
0       1       3      3  data,data2,data3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['all_unknown'] = df.iloc[:, 3:].apply(','.join, axis=1)
```

if you also want to drop all columns after the 4th:

```
cols = df.columns[3:-1]
df.drop(cols, axis=1)
```

the `-1` is to avoid dropping the new column

Comment: `4` is an incorrect index, in python the 4th item is `3` ;)

Comment: Also, `drop` works by default on the index, it will fail in your case ;)